# How to get AWS python Lambda to return status codes that will be recognised by cloudwatch

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I'm running an AWS python lambda on a trigger and would like to monitor it using cloudwatch. I'm monitoring cloudwatch "invocations" and "errors" but the are always the same.

What do I need to do in python when the lambda returns so that cloud watch will recognise it as a success/error.

The data that is passed to the lambda will sometimes be poorly formatted and will not be able to be processed - I'd like to return an error at that point that will be recognised by cloudwatch.

I've tried the following but the errors and invocations count is always the same.

`return '{"statusCode": 200,"body": "OK"}'`
`return '{"StatusCode": 200,"body": "OK"}'`

`return '{"statusCode": 500,"body": "Error"}'`
`return '{"StatusCode": 500,"body": "Error"}'`

What am I missing not understanding?

Updated code with follow but still doesn't work:

`````
if badrecord==False:
   return json.dumps({"statusCode": 200,"body": {"message": "OK"}})
else:
   return json.dumps({"statusCode": 500,"body": {"message": "Error Bad Record"}})````
`````

Answer (score 0):

Yeah my bad, you might be looking for api gateway logging to cloudwatch. AWS has a great walkthrough on how to do that.
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cloudwatch-logs/